# SQL optimization join

Tags: sql, optimization, join

I must to have some SQL queries every day, it generally involves joins 
I'd like to know which is the most properly way to do a join for example in this tables

```
A("a",x,y) 
B("b",'a',z,w)
```

where a and b are primary keys,
which is better?

```
SELECT * 
FROM a,b 
WHERE a.a=b.a AND a.x<constant
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM a WHERE x < constant) t, b
WHERE t.a=b.a
```

It means, is better make first the where clause and after make the join or I can do the join and after filter by where

thank you!

Comment: Both queries are a cross join.  I'd say "better" depends on what kind of data you're after, which is something you don't quite explain.

Comment: check your query execution plan. I bet they're processed the same way

Answer (score 2):

The first approach of your's is the better one. The second approach is having a sub query and having a sub query in your queries would reduce the performance. Because in your second approach the query has to first fetch all the rows in table and then filter it based on the join condition but in the first approach the query will only fetch the rows that match the join condition which is always faster. Hope I have made is as simple as possible...!

Comment: I disagree, because an assumption was made on the size of the data (if the data is relatively small in size, then there shouldn't be a noticeable impact on performance), and on the question being asked - if they're going after other data, then it might be more efficient to use other types of joins.

Comment: Yes I have made an assumption on the size of the data. I have assumed that the data in both the tables being big if not huge. But I feel even if the amount of data is in thousands my analogy still holds good. Pls correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Abhi you are quite right. The join is always faster.

Comment: Thank you @Alvin. If we still have doubts on this we can use a query performance measurement tool to make ourselves clear on this...!

Answer (score 0):

Smart optimizer(e.g. oracle's) will execute both of them in the same way :

If the result of `SELECT * FROM a WHERE x < constant`  is relatively small :

[Nested loop join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_loop_join)

Otherwise :

[Hash join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_join)

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing the code as cleanly and clearly as possible, for the particular problem at hand, rather than micro-managing the optimizer. In the past week when I have used both of those query styles. What-ever amount of data you are testing on today, I can guarantee you will be running in production on much more data next year.

You will always have to tune the queries that run slow in production, but guessing which ones those are is a mugs game.  This time is much better spent than guessing which queries **might** be a problem, and optimizing all of them in advance.